# ObjectDisposedException when returning AsAsyncEnumerable()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, async-await

In my .NET Core 3 WebAPI project, I have the following, simple method call:

```cs
[HttpGet("ViewerRoles")]
public IAsyncEnumerable<ViewerRole> GetViewList() {
    using var db = new MpaContext();

    return db.ViewerRoles.AsAsyncEnumerable();
}
```

This throws me an ObjectDisposedException. `AsAsyncEnumerable()` is relatively new and I can't find any appropriate examples of how to use it in such situations. Should I just remove the `using` keyword and the Entity Framework database connection magically disposes itself? Or is there another trick?

Answer (score 3):

You have two options. Either enumerate the `IAsyncEnumerable` inside your `GetViewList` method:

```
[HttpGet("ViewerRoles")]
public async IAsyncEnumerable<ViewerRole> GetViewList()
{
    using var db = new MpaContext();
    await foreach (var item in db.ViewerRoles.AsAsyncEnumerable().ConfigureAwait(false))
    {
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

...or install the [`System.Interactive.Async`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Interactive.Async/) package and use the static `AsyncEnumerableEx.Using` method:

```
[HttpGet("ViewerRoles")]
public IAsyncEnumerable<ViewerRole> GetViewList()
{
    return AsyncEnumerableEx.Using(() => new MpaContext(),
        db => db.ViewerRoles.AsAsyncEnumerable());
}
```

Here is the signature of the `AsyncEnumerableEx.Using` method:

```
public static IAsyncEnumerable<TSource> Using<TSource, TResource>(
    Func<TResource> resourceFactory,
    Func<TResource, IAsyncEnumerable<TSource>> enumerableFactory)
    where TResource : IDisposable;
```

Unfortunately it seems that there is no online documentation available for this library.

Comment: Which option would you prefer personally? There's also another idea posted by Jonas Hoegh posted below.

Comment: @AndréReichelt both options are functionally equivalent, and equally efficient. So it's a matter of taste. About Jonas Høgh's suggestion, my knowledge is not enough to judge it.

Answer (score 1):

`using` statement in this case scopes your dbContext to function scope, so the correct way would be to enumerate before returning from action, otherwise you returning something what is cannot be correctly evaluated later (after function returned and context disposed)

alternatively, you can move dbContext creation to controller's scope, which is can be request scope (it is not that hart to implement via framework's DI and DI will take care about everything with IDisposable and scoped to request "magically")

Answer (score 1):

You should implement `IDisposable` on your controller, and dispose the `DbContext` in the controller's `Dispose` method

Comment: Compared to Theodor Zoulias' ideas, which one would you prefer?

Answer (score 1):

I have also found the approach to use the method `Response.RegisterForDispose()`. But I still do not know which approach is the most promising.

```cs
[HttpGet("ViewerRoles")]
public IAsyncEnumerable<ViewerRole> GetViewList() {
    MpaContext db = new MpaContext();

    Response.RegisterForDispose(db);

    return db.ViewerRoles.AsAsyncEnumerable();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see all answers have its own point and all of them true. So, I can only make some clarifications on them.

You should choose a moment of disposing object depending on how you expose it. For example, your original code implicitly exposes `MpaContext db` to AspNet pipeline and you can't dispose `db` until netcore done his work with it. So, you can register disposing of it by `Response.RegisterForDispose()`, as you mentioned. But, it's uncommon because you don't have access to `Response` usually - you can do this only inside Controller, or if you share it with Controller dependencies, but it will rise code complexity.

That's why you can avoid this by relying on lifetime of controller. Since, it's in request scope it will live until response was sent. So, you can create your `db` as controller dependency and hold it within a property. Also you should implement `IDisposable` on controller.

```cs
public class RoleController : IDisposable
{
    private MpaContext DbContext { get; }

    public RoleController()
    {
        DbContext = new MpaContext();
    }

    [HttpGet( "ViewerRoles" )]
    public IAsyncEnumerable<ViewerRole> GetViewList()
    {
        return DbContext.ViewerRoles.AsAsyncEnumerable();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        DbContext.Dispose();
    }
}
```

In this case you can stick to this pattern even if you will move your logic to some other class (as it supposed to be, I believe). But still, if you manually create disposable objects you should care about disposing them. That's the moment when DI comes to help.

By using DI you can forget about disposing objects that was created by DI. DI will call `Dispose()` on any dependency when lifecycle of it ends. Register your `MpaContext` by calling `AddDbContextPool<MpaContext>()` or `AddDbContext<MpaContext>()` if you use EntityFramework under `MpaContext`. With this approach you will get clear code of your controller.

```cs
public class RoleController
{
    private MpaContext DbContext { get; }

    public RoleController( MpaContext dbContext )
    {
        DbContext = dbContext;
    }

    [HttpGet( "ViewerRoles" )]
    public IAsyncEnumerable<ViewerRole> GetViewList()
    {
        return DbContext.ViewerRoles.AsAsyncEnumerable();
    }
}
```

If you don't want to expose `MpaContext` to controller and want to create it manually inside `GetViewList()`, you can still enumerate result within the action method and dispose context as Theodor Zoulias answered. But why would you, if you can simply delegate this work to DI.

Comment: So if I use dependency injection, the object will be disposed automatically?

Comment: @AndréReichelt Yes, it's true. For more information you could refer to this [docs.microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#scope-validation). See sections **Scope validation** and **Disposal of services**.

Comment: Also, you can find this article helpful [docs.microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection)

Comment: Thank you very much!